# Broken pipe or closed connection Magento2 Bulk Async API

Tags: magento2.4

Anyone have experience using the Magento's bulk API async/V1/products.

I tried using it with RabbitMQ but it was throwing error like connection time out after 3 seconds, I fixed that but still I'm getting exception Broken Pipe or Close Connection.

Can anyone help on that.

Thanks

Comment: Am also facing the same issue. It keep throwing Broken pipe or closed connection error.

Comment: @seeni can you share you env file configuration?

Comment: I have fixed this issue by running following commands,
rabbitmqctl stop_app
rabbitmqctl start_app

Answer (score 1):

Following commands helped to resolve this issue,

```
rabbitmqctl stop_app 
rabbitmqctl start_app
```